# build google breakpad stackwalk

Tags: google-breakpad

I can build the google breakpad client, the stackwalker can convert the dump to human readable txt file. But there is no gyp file to make vs2008 solution. Does anyone know how to build the stackwalker on windows. Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain how you converted the dump to a readable file? And how did you compile the converter? thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The stackwalker tool doesn't build using Visual C++ currently. You can build it with Cygwin if you install that whole toolchain. If you'd find it useful there's a prebuilt Cygwin minidump_stackwalk binary that Mozilla uses on [our build machines](http://hg.mozilla.org/build/tools/raw-file/755e58ebc9d4/breakpad/win32/minidump_stackwalk.exe).

Along with the matching Cygwin support DLLs:
[cygwin1.dll](http://hg.mozilla.org/build/tools/raw-file/755e58ebc9d4/breakpad/win32/cygwin1.dll), 
[cygstdc++-6.dll](http://hg.mozilla.org/build/tools/raw-file/755e58ebc9d4/breakpad/win32/cygstdc%2B%2B-6.dll), 
[cyggcc_s-1.dll](http://hg.mozilla.org/build/tools/raw-file/755e58ebc9d4/breakpad/win32/cyggcc_s-1.dll).

It's slightly out-of-date but should work fine.

Also note that you should be able to load Windows minidump files directly into a debugger on Windows, like Visual C++ or WinDBG.

Comment: This version unfortunately doesn't have the most useful parameter yet ( -s : Output stack contents). Is there a newer build from more current sources?